# Different behavior of app while testing on device and simulator ?

Tags: iphone, testing, ios-simulator, device

When I test my app on simulator,

When user tap the phone's Home button, app goes inactive and when opens again by tapping the app icon, it become active **by showing the same view which was shown before tapping Home button.**

BUT When test on Device,

When user tap the phone's Home button, app goes inactive and when opens again by tapping the app icon, it become active **but NOT showing the same view which was shown before tapping Home button and shows the first view (here Login view of app ).**

**Why it behaves differently??**  What I can do here to make app behaves as on simulator??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is your simulator may be of 4.0 or 4.2. or latest version.

Hence , when you click on simulator home button app should not removed from background and app is running on background.

hence you clicked again app icon it will open same view.

while your iphone (device) may be 3.0 hence it is not multitasking.

hence , when clicked on home button app would not remain in background and removed from background . hence when you again touch on app icon it should open from begining.

**MULTITASKING** section from this link should help you..
http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-apple-iphone-ios-3-and-ios-4/

Comment: Thank you very much. :) that was helpful...  suppose if I release my app, will the same happen on user's device ?? (different behavior on different device versions) What prevention I can take?

Comment: it depends on user's devices version.. and for that when you release your app you have to set deployment target minimum (may be 3.0 for iphone and 3.2 for ipad).so it can run on any device...thanks.